# Change PayPal email based on WooCommerce order items product tags

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to find a solution to my problem. I would like to change the PayPal email based on the WooCommerce product tag.
Example: for clothing, footwear and bags tags put the email emailpaypal1@domain.com .....
If the tags are snow, sun, garden, then put the email paypal2@domain.com etc ...

I found this code after several searches but i can't get it to work with tags. I tried them all but failed :(. Could anyone give me the modified code for the tags? Thank you very much !!

```
// 1. Switch PayPal email for Product ID
add_filter( 'woocommerce_paypal_args' , 'switch_paypal_email_based_product', 9999, 2 );
function switch_paypal_email_based_product( $paypal_args, $order ) {
 
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

        // ENTER PRODUCT ID HERE
        if ( 123456 == $item->get_product_id() ) {
            // ENTER OTHER PAYPAL EMAIL HERE
            $paypal_args['business'] = 'another-paypal@example.com';
            break;
        }
    }
    return $paypal_args;
}
 
// 2. Avoid IPN Failure after switching PayPal email for Product ID
require_once WC()->plugin_path() . '/includes/gateways/paypal/includes/class-wc-gateway-paypal-ipn-handler.php';
 
class WC_Gateway_Paypal_IPN_Handler_Switch extends WC_Gateway_Paypal_IPN_Handler { 
    
    protected function validate_receiver_email( $order, $receiver_email ) {
 
        if ( strcasecmp( trim( $receiver_email ), trim( $this->receiver_email ) ) !== 0 ) {
 
            // ENTER HERE SAME PAYPAL EMAIL USED ABOVE
            if ( $receiver_email != 'another-paypal@example.com' ) {
 
                WC_Gateway_Paypal::log( "IPN Response is for another account: {$receiver_email}. Your email is {$this->receiver_email}" );
                $order->update_status( 'on-hold', sprintf( __( 'Validation error: PayPal IPN response from a different email address (%s).', 'woocommerce' ), $receiver_email ) );
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
 
new WC_Gateway_Paypal_IPN_Handler_Switch();
```

### Update

I put it in the `function.php` file of the child theme, but it gives me an error in the line that I am attaching to you. Did I copy badly? :(. Did I forget something? Thank you very much !!

```
Error: syntax error, unexpected 'array' (T_ARRAY), expecting ')'
```

---

```
if ( ! in_array( $receiver_email array('paypal1@domain.com', 'paypal2@domain.com') ) {
```

the error he gives me in this line ... but honestly I don't know if the program that is wordpress understood if it is in this line or if you are wrong :(. It does not make me save the code for this problem ...

```
Error: syntax error, unexpected 'array' (T_ARRAY), expecting ')'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle specific product tags on order items, you can us WordPress `has_term()` function this way, replacing your first hooked function with the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_paypal_args' , 'switch_paypal_email_based_product_tags', 9999, 2 );
function switch_paypal_email_based_product_tags( $paypal_args, $order ) {
    // Here define your product tags
    $tag_terms1 = array('clothing', 'footwear', 'bags'); 
    $tag_terms2 = array('snow', 'sun', 'garden');

    // Here define your emails
    $email1     = 'paypal1@domain.com';
    $email2     = 'paypal2@domain.com';
 
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        if ( has_term( $tag_terms1, 'product_tag', $item->get_product_id() ) ) {
            $paypal_args['business'] = $email1;
            break;
        } elseif ( has_term( $tag_terms2, 'product_tag', $item->get_product_id() ) ) {
            $paypal_args['business'] = $email2;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $paypal_args;
}

// Avoid IPN Failure after switching PayPal email for order items product tags 
require_once WC()->plugin_path() . '/includes/gateways/paypal/includes/class-wc-gateway-paypal-ipn-handler.php';
 
class WC_Gateway_Paypal_IPN_Handler_Switch extends WC_Gateway_Paypal_IPN_Handler { 
    
    protected function validate_receiver_email( $order, $receiver_email ) {
 
        if ( strcasecmp( trim( $receiver_email ), trim( $this->receiver_email ) ) !== 0 ) {
 
            // Here set same paypal emails used above in the array
            if ( ! in_array( $receiver_email array('paypal1@domain.com', 'paypal2@domain.com') ) ) {
 
                WC_Gateway_Paypal::log( "IPN Response is for another account: {$receiver_email}. Your email is {$this->receiver_email}" );
                $order->update_status( 'on-hold', sprintf( __( 'Validation error: PayPal IPN response from a different email address (%s).', 'woocommerce' ), $receiver_email ) );
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
 
new WC_Gateway_Paypal_IPN_Handler_Switch();
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

**Important note:** This will not work as expected for example if you have an order item from **"clothing"** and another from **"garden"** in the same order.

Related: [Sending only order number instead of item names to PayPal in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221852/sending-only-order-number-instead-of-item-names-to-paypal-in-woocommerce/46261981#46261981)